# Make my search box work?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm creating a web browser and it has a search box and go button. Could you help me set this up? Is there also a way to use the html code search bar that you use on website?

This is my code:

```
     private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        string site;
        site = textBox1.Text;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(
             new Uri("http://m.bing.com/search?q=", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: have you tried appending the textBox1.Text to the bing url?

Comment: are you getting to Bing currently? Is the only problem that bing isn't searching?

Comment: I'm trying to program the text from textBox1 to search bing when go is pressed.

Comment: I understand that. Currently when you press the button does anything happen? Do you see the bing homepage? If so it's an easy change, if not I can't help you much

Comment: it goes to bing search and searches nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bassed on your comments it goes to bing and searches nothing.

To fix this you need to populate the querystring parameter "q". This is really quite simple:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string site;
    site = textBox1.Text;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(
         new Uri("http://m.bing.com/search?q=" + site, UriKind.Absolute));
```

You could also use the `String.Format` function to get:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string site;
    site = textBox1.Text;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(
         new Uri(System.String.Format("http://m.bing.com/search?q={0}", site), UriKind.Absolute));
```

Either of these should work for you, my personal preference is the 2nd one.